# How can I programmatically set a default select option in for loop?

Tags: forms

I have a `for` loop in my code that creates elements in a table using data from the database. Each row has a select element, where the default option should correspond to what's stored in the database:

```
$listmode = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => [
        'none' => t('Unlisted'),
        'black' => t('Blacklist'),
        'white' => t('Whitelist'),
    ],
    '#attributes' => ['id' => ''],
    '#default_value' => '',
];

$rows = array();
foreach (BlocceConfigStorage::getBlocks() as $block){
    //I really wish there were a better way to do this
    if ($block->listing == null || $block->listing == 2){
        $default = 'none'; //set select to unlisted
    }
    else if ($block->listing == 0){
        $default = 'black'; //set select to blacklist
    }
    else if ($block->listing == 1){
        $default = 'white'; //set select to whitelist
    }
    $listmode['#default_value'] = $default;
    $pre = $listmode;
    $pre['#attributes']['id'] = 'select-block-'. $block->id;
    $tlist = drupal_render($pre);
    $rows[] = [
            'data' => [$block->id, $block->info, $tlist]
        ];
}
```

I attach the generated rows here:

```
$form['table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'table',
    '#header' => $thead,
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'blocce_blocks',
        ),
    );
```

I've tried messing around with the sample found [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Select.php/class/Select/8.2.x) and adding a single `listmode` select to the form and setting the default. Both of them worked on their own; I've also tried `pre['#default_value'] = $default`, but that also was availed me nothing. I suspect that the problem either lies in the `drupal_render($pre);` (without this, however, the `select`s refuse to show up) or that the for loop itself is the problem.

**Tl;dr:** How do I set the default select option in the for loop?

*Edit:* I'm using Drupal 8, but from what I've seen, this doesn't seem to have changed much from Drupal 7.

Comment: It has changed a bit since D7 (this method also wouldn't have worked for D7 BTW, it's a bit more convoluted). There's a good example [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1876710) that should help; put simply, it's the form builder that deals with setting values, not a render function, and with your current code the form doesn't contain the selects as elements (they're just being passed as an argument to the table's render callback), so values aren't set

Comment: @Clive Thank you for the link! It definitely set me going in the right direction, and now I've got it working.